# Black Screen after Resume from Sleep (Kubuntu)

Tags: laptop, kubuntu, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Black screen after wakeup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95602/black-screen-after-wakeup)

I know there is a lot of other posts like this, but I have been looking for hours and I still haven't found any solution.

I have recently installed Kubuntu Linux along side my Windows 7, the sleep on my Win7 works fine and resumes like normal. When I am loaded into Kubuntu, and I put my laptop to sleep, it goes into sleep as normal. When I go to RESUME from the sleep, the screen stays solid black, it doesn't light up, no blinking curser or anything. The Wi-Fi light is 'off' (orange) and I cannot turn it on. The Caps lock and the Num lock lights on the keyboard blink slowly. I hear something on the inside of the computer start to spin.

I am not very experienced with Kubuntu/Linux, but I do know a bunch of computer terminology, I am still far from an expert though.

I have about 300GB designated to my Win7 stuff, and another partition with about 100GB for my Kubuntu Linux.

My computers specs are as follows:
Windows 7 64-bit
I have the most recent version of Kubuntu because I just downloaded it a few days ago and updated it yesterday.
AMD Athlon Duel-Core processor
4GB of RAM
And it is a HP G61 Laptop

Comment: How big is your swap? For the sleep function to work, the swap has to be at least the size of your RAM.

Comment: What is the model of your laptop, not the series? Does it do this after you lock/switch users?

Comment: did this ever get resolved