# Black screen after wakeup

Tags: 11.10, suspend

HP w2207h (HDMI screen) , HP 6235fr under UBUNTU 11.10 (Nvidia GT220):

After suspending for a long time, wakeup my PC with USB.
Boots up but black screen.No screen since start of booting.
The machine seems to be hung , but it is still working ...
It is just blind.

**Suspend/Resume doesn't solve the problem.**
**Power On Reset of screen solves the problem.**
Problem doesn't exist with Windows 7 (dual boot).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds similar to a problem I posted a question about: [Why does my screen not return to full brightness when waking a Lenovo B570 from sleep mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93630/why-does-my-screen-not-return-to-full-brightness-when-waking-a-lenovo-b570-from)

In this case there is a bug in the kernel which is causing the screen to be black when returning from suspended state (actually the brightness is just turned down to the lowest level). This is the bug report for the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/872652 If this sounds like your problem (can't be sure as you haven't supplied much in the way of details) then there is a solution which worked for me in Comment #55 of the bug report which involves updating the kernel. When the next official update to the Ubuntu kernel is released the patch will be applied also.

Here you would have to add the following ppa to your system: **ppa:kamalmostafa/stuck-backlight** and enter:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Though please be VERY VERY careful and make sure the situation really does apply to you before making such changes as this, as updating the kernel can cause a lot of problems. This would only be effective if you are running the 11.10 version of Ubuntu.

Comment: My current kernel version is 3.0.0.17. The link you give states that the issue is solved from version 3.0.0.15. Despite this I am encountering the same issue when waking up my machine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way later on this, but this Q&A is listed as the canonical original for another marked duplicate. I've been experiencing this problem very intermittently on an 18.04 version and finally stumbled on what appears to be a solution. I have success with ctrl-alt-F which is saving me from having to reboot. (i'm going to nominate the other question for re-opening since the other answer appears extremely narrow in its range of applicability.)